# Reset 302 after HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web API endpoint that's utilizing a third party library that calls

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(someUrl, true);
```

The problem is that I want a status 200 from my endpoint, with `someUrl` passsed a response in the body.

I can extract someUrl using `HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation`. But despite my web API endpoint returning a result with the url and status explicit 200, the Response.Redirect still seem to take presidence and return a 302. How can I prevent that?

To illustrate the problem:

```
[HttpPost, Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Execute()
{
    // third party library does this:
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://google.com", true);

    var url = HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation;

    return Ok(new { url });
}
```

Comment: You set the `endResponse` in `Response.Redirect` to true, which means the code below will never be executed. Not sure if that fixes your response issue though.

Comment: @VDWWD well I guess I can't "revert" that later on in the code that I have control over?

Comment: You can do `Response.Redirect("https://google.com");` Then the rest of the code will execute....

Comment: @VDWWD I see, the thing is that I don't control that line of code, so guess I'm out of luck :D